# What's the default ScaleType of ImageView?

Tags: android

What's the default ScaleType of ImageView?If I put an image which is 400 pixels x 400 pixels on a normal screen (320x480) without specifying ScaleType, how will the image be scaled?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/big_image"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why has this been marked as duplicate if the other question was asked 2 years later? Not too mention circular references...

Comment: @p.s.w.g could you please unmark this as duplicate? The other question is asked about 2.5 years after this question. The link to other question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828720/what-is-default-scale-type-of-imageview

Answer (score 115, accepted):

[FIT_CENTER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html):

> [`ImageView.ScaleType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) `FIT_CENTER`
>
> Scale the image using [`CENTER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#CENTER). From XML, use this syntax: `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`.

Comment: Be careful!! For an of ImageView the default ScaleType value is FIT_CENTER, but for a Button is "fitXY"