# What is default scale type of ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

I can set options for scaling the bounds of an image to the bounds of an `ImageView` using `setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType)`.

What is default `ImageView.ScaleType`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks to be [`ScaleType.FIT_CENTER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html#FIT_CENTER):

```
private void initImageView() {
    mMatrix     = new Matrix();
    mScaleType  = ScaleType.FIT_CENTER;
}
```

Links to the source code of ImageView: [Android 4.1.1 r6.1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.1.1_r6.1/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java#164)