# Adjust icon size of Floating action button (fab)

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, material-components-android, android-icons

[image: Floating button]
The new floating action button should be **56dp x 56dp** and the icon inside it should be **24dp x 24dp**. So the space between icon and button should be **16dp**.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_add"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_oval"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_48dp" />
```

ripple_oval.xml

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

And this is the result I get: 
[image: Floating button result] 
I used the icon from *\material-design-icons-1.0.0\content\drawable-hdpi\ic_add_black_48dp.png* 
https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/releases/tag/1.0.1

How to make the **size of the icon** inside the button be **exactly** as described in guidelines ?

http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-floating-action-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59455009/3974530

Answer (score 198, accepted):

As your content is 24dp x 24dp you should use [24dp icon](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/content/drawable-hdpi/ic_add_black_24dp.png). And then set `android:scaleType="center"` in your ImageButton to avoid auto resize.

Comment: Can you explain or drop a link to some site, why for example in **drawable-hdpi** folder there are _18dp.png, _24dp.png, _36dp.png, _48dp.png images.

Comment: I don't understand your question, there are 18dp, 24dp, 36dp and 48dp for different size images.

Comment: Do you remember the old Android_Design_Icons which had only one variant of the icon in hdpi folder which was 48px x 48px. Why now in hdpi folder there are 4 different resolution for the same icon i.e. 27px x 27 px, 36px x 36px, 54px x 54px, 72px x 72px ?

Comment: yep I remember but I can't  explain why these new icons are in multiple sizes... (to get them super clean when they are used ?). Hope someone has an answer to that

Comment: Is **android:scaleType** applicable to an ImageButton because I don't get any suggestions when I use CTRL+SPACE. Without that tag it gives the same effect. Maybe for ImageButton *android:scaleType* is set by default to *center*

Comment: ImageButton is a subclass of ImageView so you have a scaleType attribut and default scaleType is [ScaleType.FIT_CENTER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828720/what-is-default-scale-type-of-imageview)

Comment: Then I will not change it. I think the default value ScaleType.FIT_CENTER is safer to use for an ImageButton.

Comment: android:scaleType="center"
android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
are settings work on almost all views

Comment: No longer works with com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01

Answer (score 197):

Try to use `app:maxImageSize="56dp"` instead of the above answers after you update your support library to v28.0.0

Comment: Any ways, you don't get this in 28.0.0 version, you will get it in androidx.

Comment: I haven't switched to AndroidX, this is what I am using: api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

Comment: This worked for me but I would like more information to understand why defining a `maxIconSize` changes the icon size.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to set maxImageSize programmatically? I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 133):

There are three key XML attributes for custom FABs:

- `app:fabSize`: Either "mini" (40dp), "normal"(56dp)**(default)**  or "auto"
- `app:fabCustomSize`: This will decide the overall FAB size.
- `app:maxImageSize`: This will decide the icon size.

---

Example:

```
app:fabCustomSize="64dp" 
app:maxImageSize="32dp"
```

The FAB padding (the space between the icon and the background circle, aka *ripple*) is calculated **implicitly** by:

```
4-edge padding = (fabCustomSize - maxImageSize) / 2.0 = 16
```

---

*Note that the margins of the fab can be set by the usual `android:margin` xml tag properties.*

Comment: Can you please tell me how to set maxImageSize programmatically? I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: @Chitrang According to the API documentation, there are no public methods to set the FAB's "maxImageSize". However, there is a "setCustomSize" method... See if it works out for you. In the worst case, you need to create a new FAB view and append it into your layout... since there is no way to dynamically set attributes in XML without the view's setter method.

Comment: maxImageSize worked for me for showing full drawable in floating button.

Answer (score 125):

Make this entry in dimens

```
<!--Floating action button-->
<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">36dp</dimen>
```

Here 36dp is icon size on floating point button. This will set 36dp size for all icons for floating action button.

**Updates As Per Comments**

If you want to set icon size to particular Floating Action Button just go with Floating action button attributes like app:fabSize="normal" and android:scaleType="center".

```
  <!--app:fabSize decides size of floating action button You can use normal, auto or mini as per need-->
  app:fabSize="normal" 

  <!--android:scaleType decides how the icon drawable will be scaled on Floating action button. You can use center(to show scr image as original), fitXY, centerCrop, fitCenter, fitEnd, fitStart, centerInside.-->
  android:scaleType="center"
```

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work with https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton. It works when you are using androids FloatingActionButton

Comment: Yeaaaah but I don't Want to do it across the app!

Comment: @StarWind0 I you have to use fabSize and scaleType attributes if want to apply for single floating action button. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 31):

The design guidelines defines two sizes and unless there is a strong reason to deviate from using either, the size can be controlled with the `fabSize` XML attribute of the `FloatingActionButton` component.

Consider specifying using either `app:fabSize="normal"` or `app:fabSize="mini"`, e.g.:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_24px"
   app:fabSize="mini" />
```

Answer (score 18):

```
<ImageButton
        android:background="@drawable/action_button_bg"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_48dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:elevation="8dp"/>
```

With the background you provided it results in below button on my device (Nexus 7 2012)

[image]

Looks good to me.

Comment: I set the padding but it does nothing. And the right padding would be 16 dp not 32dp

Answer (score 16):

What's your goal?

If set icon image size to bigger one:

1. Make sure to have a bigger image size than your target size `(so you can set max image size for your icon)`
2. My target icon image size is **84dp** & fab size is **112dp**:

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:src= <image here>
       app:fabCustomSize="112dp"
       app:fabSize="auto"
       app:maxImageSize="84dp" />
   ```

Answer (score 11):

If you are using androidx 1.0.0 and are using a custom fab size, you will have to specify the custom size using

```
app:fabCustomSize="your custom size in dp"
```

By deafult the size is 56dp and there is another variation that is the small sized fab which is 40dp, if you are using anything you will have to specify it for the padding to be calculated correctly

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! You don't even need to set `layout_width` and `layout_height`. It just works. This is also available on `com.android.support:design:28.0.0`

Answer (score 6):

You can play with the following settings of FloatingActionButton : android:scaleType and app:maxImageSize. As for me, I've got a desirable result if android:scaleType="centerInside" and app:maxImageSize="56dp".

Answer (score 5):

As `FAB` is like `ImageView` so You can use `scaleType` attribute to change the icon size likewise `ImageView`. Default `scaleType` for a `FAB` is `fitCenter`. You can use `center` and `centerInside` to make icon small and large respectively.

All values for `scaleType` attribute are - `center, centerCrop, centerInside, fitCenter, fitEnd, fitStart, fitXY` and `matrix`.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html for more details.

Answer (score 3):

off of @IRadha's answer
in vector drawable setting `android:height="_dp"`
and setting the scale type to `android:scaleType="center"`
sets the drawable to whatever size was set

Answer (score 2):

Using ExtendedFloatingActionButton, this solved the issue for me:

```
app:iconSize="<x>dp"
```

I've tried `iconPadding` or `fabCustomSize` but I haven't seem any changes

Comment: Thanks.  Took a while to find this answer for extended FAB

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set your FAB icon size by using,

> final FloatingActionButton button = new FloatingActionButton(context);
>
> button.setCustomSize(50);

Answer (score -1):

```
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="#FBFAFA"
    app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:maxImageSize="84dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/resim"
    app:tint="#E81C1C"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="325dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="517dp" />
```

I Handled It This Way

Comment: id and srcCompat I prefer that you adjust these parts according to yourself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).