# FloatingActionButton with text instead of image

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, floating-action-button

I'm trying to figure out how can be modified FloatingActionButton from android support library. Can it be used with the text instead of image?

Something like this one:

[image]

I see it extends ImageButton so I think not. Am I right?

Is this correct in terms of Material Design in general?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

With API 28 you can simply add text to Fabs using:

Visit: https://material.io/develop/android/components/extended-floating-action-button/

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:contentDescription="@string/extended_fab_content_desc"
      android:text="@string/extended_fab_label"
      app:icon="@drawable/ic_plus_24px"
      app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
      app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

Comment: Hey, they finally did it. Probably that's the best way to use it now. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"

Comment: From https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android
you have to use the latest 

    `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'`

Comment: it becomes a round corner rect,how to make it a round button ?

Comment: make all corner radius `30dp`

Comment: "with text instead of image"

Comment: Caution, Extended FAB doesn't play well with BottomAppBar. Especially the cutout is gone, and animations too.

Comment: limitation of this is that icon must be a png.

Answer (score 114):

Thanks to all.

Here is easy workaround which I found for this question. Works correctly for Android 4+, for Android 5+ is added specific parameter android:elevation to draw TextView over FloatingActionButton.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:color/transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@android:string/ok"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: TextView showing shadow due to elevation properties,

Comment: Try to add the attributes `android:layout_margin="20dp"` in FloatingActionButton to resolvethe shadow issues. Waiting for better solution for it

Comment: add `android:includeFontPadding="false"` to `TextView` tag for better performance

Comment: android:elevation="16dp" is only compatible with API 21 and higher.

Answer (score 64):

convert a text into bitmap and use it. its super easy.

```
fab.setImageBitmap(textAsBitmap("OK", 40, Color.WHITE));

//method to convert your text to image
public static Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize, int textColor) {
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setColor(textColor);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    float baseline = -paint.ascent(); // ascent() is negative
    int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.0f); // round
    int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.0f);
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, baseline, paint);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Perfect but text size is not changing.

Comment: @Ankur_009 its changing. Try increasing the value by quite a size as its in float.

Comment: sweet, with few changes I made it work to convert icon fonts to drawables

Comment: @Ankur_009: The button space is limited, that is why you do not see a change in text size. So if your text is already taking the full space on the button, making the text bigger will have no effect.

Comment: @pratz9999 i even set it to 1000 but still its not changing

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal Please share the code in some online text editor so that I can help.

Comment: @pratz9999 i used the exact same code. i am attaching my fab xml
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/teacher_create_notice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:backgroundTint="#fff"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal can you share the implementation of it in java?

Comment: @pratz9999 Here is the code.. 
createButton = view.findViewById(R.id.teacher_create_notice);
        createButton.setImageBitmap(textAsBitmap(" + ", 32.f, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))); 
I tried every possible value for textsize from 20, 20.0, 200, 200.0 etc. Still no result.

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal It is working fine. You have to either increase the width and height of FAB or follow the URL below to increase the drawable area in FAB. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484126/adjust-icon-size-of-floating-action-button-fab

Comment: @pratz9999 thanks for the link will surely give it a try.

Answer (score 33):

FABs are usually used in `CoordinatorLayout`s. You can use this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"               
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

      <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:text="OK"
              android:elevation="6dp"
              android:textSize="18dp"
              android:textColor="#fff"
              app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
              app:layout_anchorGravity="center"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is what does the work

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
```

Result:

[image: The Result]

If you're using some `layout_behavior` for your FAB, you'll have to make a similar `layout_behavior` for the `TextView`

Comment: Getting error android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Comment: Are you sure that your FloatingActionButton is inside CoordinatorLayout ?

Comment: @Ankur_009 this error `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup` is probably because you have put `TextView` inside FAB. Please check with OP where does the tag closed.

Comment: The elevation of the TextView must also be larger than that of FAB, otherwise it will hide behind the FAB

Comment: Superb answer!!

Comment: Any way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Along with layout_anchorGravity="center" it's also necessary to add android:gravity="center" for longer texts.

Answer (score 21):

You can't set text for `FloatingActionButton` from the support library, but what you can do, is create a text image directly from android studio : `File -> New -> Image Asset`, and then use it for your button.

In the terms of **Material Design**; they didn't mention using text with `FloatingActionButton`, and I don't see any reason for doing that since you don't really have much space for a text.

Comment: Text like "OK", "YES", "NO", "GO" fits perfectly inside FAB's..........

Comment: For words in FABs, see Extended Tabs: https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#extended-fab

Answer (score 10):

I was needing text in a FAB but instead I just went with a TextView with a circular drawable background:

```
  <TextView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="AuthId"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"/>
```

Here is the drawable(circle_backgroung.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

<solid
    android:color="#666666"/>

<size
    android:width="60dp"
    android:height="60dp"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: There is no ripple animation with such solution

Answer (score 3):

It is available out of box.

[The documentation here](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/android#regular-fabs) describes 3 types of FABs.

[image]

The most common Error, in this case, is an attempt to add text with FloatingActionButton. This is not how FAB is designed.

**Use ExtendedFloatingActionButton when a LABEL is required.**

```
 <!-- ExtendedFloatingActionButton to be used with TEXT.
   Note that it uses app:icon for icon image-->

  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/extended_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:contentDescription="@string/extended_fab_content_desc"
    android:text="@string/extended_fab_label"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_plus_24px"/>


  <!-- FloatingActionButtonto be used when there is no text required.
   Note that it uses app:srcCompat and not the app:icon for icon image-->

  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
      android:layout_margin="16dp"
      android:contentDescription="@string/fab_content_desc"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_24"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer of @NandanKumarSingh https://stackoverflow.com/a/39965170/5279156 works but i have made some changes with fab **in code** (not xml because they will be overwritten in class methods)

```
fab.setTextBitmap("ANDROID", 100f, Color.WHITE)
fab.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER
fab.adjustViewBounds = false
```

Where `setTextBitmap` is an extension for `ImageView` class with similar functionality but it supports *multilne text*

```
fun ImageView.setTextBitmap(text: String, textSize: Float, textColor: Int) {
    val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    paint.textSize = textSize
    paint.color = textColor
    paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.LEFT
    val lines = text.split("\n")
    var maxWidth = 0
    for (line in lines) {
        val width = paint.measureText(line).toInt()
        if (width > maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = width
        }
    }
    val height = paint.descent() - paint.ascent()
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(maxWidth, height.toInt() * lines.size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    var y = - paint.ascent()
    for (line in lines) {
        canvas.drawText(line, 0f, y, paint)
        y += height
    }
    setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used a CardView to achieve the same result

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp80"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp80"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/dp8"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp16"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite100"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dp40">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_go_bg"
                android:text="GO"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite100" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a new material view called **ExtendedFloatingActionButton** that does this.

Here's a code example:

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_profile"
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/frameLayout_profilesAd"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/add_profile" />
```

This is the output:

[image]

You will need to add the material library to your dependencies, like so:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha02'
```

Answer (score 1):

A very little modification to [comrade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1423876/comrade) 's answer to support it for android API below 21 just add `app:elevation="0dp"` to the `FloatingActionButton`

This might help others!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own implementation, however I'm not using floating action button

This implementation is usefull for others instances:

Preview:

[image]

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="12dp"
                android:minWidth="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:src="@android:color/transparent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:elevation="16dp"
                    tools:text="+99"
                    android:textSize="9sp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
        </FrameLayout>
```