# How to implement Google Hangouts FAB like "Jump to latest" button

Tags: android, google-hangouts, floating-action-button

I've noticed in Google Hangouts that a `FloatingActionButton` like (with text) widget appears if user scrolls back in message history.

The button says "Jump to latest" with an arrow pointing down to the left of the text. It's similar to a `FloatingActionButton`.

I tried to embed a `AppCompatTextView` in a `FloatingActionButton` using `FrameLayout` with no luck.

Any ideas?

PS. I've already tried the suggestions in [FloatingActionButton with text instead of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671196/floatingactionbutton-with-text-instead-of-image) but the FAB width is not adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

here's a simplistic arch for your needs

there maybe an infinity of solutions though

```
+ FrameLayout
++++ A normal Button or ImageView if you'd like to use an icon
++++ Positioned like a modern FAB
+
++++ A scrolling Layout holding your conversations
```

When the button is clicked just scroll to the height of the scrolling view

that's it!