# How to make FAB with icon and text

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button

I'm working on customizing a floating action button (FAB) in my Android application. I'd like to modify it so that it can accommodate both an icon and text, similar to the design shown in this image:

[image: the design]

I've been searching for guidance on how to achieve this, but I haven't found a solution yet. Could someone please provide some advice or code examples on how to implement this feature while adhering to Android development best practices?

I've already tried ExtendedFloatingActionButton, but i don't know how to set the ExtendedFloatingActionButton into circle without removing the icon

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_back"
    app:iconGravity="textTop"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

this is the result of above code

[image]

Comment: Have you tried ExtendedFloatingActionButton or  Checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671196/floatingactionbutton-with-text-instead-of-image

Comment: yes i already check the ExtendedFloatingActionButton, but i can't seem to make it circle @SomanathKambar

Comment: @Blazerstrom do you have options to use any other alternative , other than FAB(Floating action button) ?

Comment: i think it must be FAB, because i want to use it to implement bottom nav bar just like in this link .... https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-a-floating-action-button-to-bottom-navigation-bar-in-android/ @Spiker

Comment: @Blazerstrom. You cant use FAB for your UI , Please find the answer I posted it will work like charm.

Comment: ok, let me try it first, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `FloatingActionButton`(FAB) cannot have text and icon both we need to customize the UI with out FAB.

Please find the below code for your expected UI , also make sure that you dont hide the Dummy Fab as it will help you in creation of curves in the bottom bar

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_dummy"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/selected_home"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:elevation="20dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/solid_circle"
            android:src="@drawable/selected_home"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/selected_home"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_fab_text"
                android:text="Fab"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`solid_circle.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#1E90FF"></solid>
</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: it work, but don't forget to change the theme parent into Theme.MaterialComponents (any material component night/light/default)

Comment: Please like(+1) this answer if its useful and helped you @Blazerstrom

Answer (score 0):

to make it circular use a background shape

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

and add this
android:background="@drawable/dialog_rounded_background"

Comment: I tried it, but the icon was lost.