# How to remove auto padding of FAB button in android?

Tags: android, material-design

I am using FAB button for profile picture but it is already having some padding. I am using following code for creating FAB button.

`<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/student"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>`

How can i remove the padding which is automatically providing by library. I have also attached an screenshot of output. I want to remove this sky blue color and increase the size of src image.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38006173/1843331

Comment: there is margin `android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"` in your xml not padding

Comment: you can change it by changing in you dimen file

Comment: dimen file is having fab_margin variable which is for getting margin from right side.

Comment: If you add some image into FAB button then it automatically take some padding. I want to remove that padding actually.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

just add this in your `dimens.xml` file

```
<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">36dp</dimen>
```

This might not work for 3rd party libraries.

Comment: I think it's cleaner to use the method of user2637476, because it doesn't override any value from the Android library.

Comment: depends on requirement i believe.

Answer (score 17):

You can changethe attribute app:maxImageSize to match the size of your image.

```
app:maxImageSize="the wanted size"
```

I find the solution safer the the overriding of the design_fab_image_size because if your app have several floating action buttons, you will only alter one.

Answer (score 1):

add this in your fab xml layout

```
android:elevation="0dp"
app:elevation="10dp"
app:useCompatPadding="true"
```

This will do the job. Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add

```
app:useCompatPadding="false"
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24961548)