# Add image in imageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I trying to make a circular image button like WhatsApp.

[image]

I tried the below code, but I am only able to create a circular `imageButton`. The image did not show in the `imageButton`.

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:paddingBottom="140dp"
        android:src = "@drawable/camera"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

**round.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="100dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#090" />

</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: Try reduce your  layout width and height of your imageButton

Comment: add solid tag in the shape <solid android:color="@color/grey_300" />

Comment: @AdeelJaved I can't see my image after add solid tag

Comment: @John i you are try to add floating button
try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484126/adjust-icon-size-of-floating-action-button-fab?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added `android:paddingBottom=140dp`. Issue with that. Check this

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:tint="@android:color/black"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You just missed `solid` tag in your custom shape file.

```
<solid android:color="#090" />
```

**Edit:**

Never try to give margin or padding which has a larger value. Just like you are using  `android:paddingBottom="140dp"`. This is not a recommended way.

Comment: After add a solid tag, whole image button turn green. I can't see the image

Answer (score 1):

For drawing a solid circle, try the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="#090"/>

    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"/>
</shape>
```

Shape type `oval` is used for drawing circles.

Answer (score 1):

**WhatsApp used a floating action button, and you can implement it in two steps.**

Add a dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
}
```

Add `com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton` to your layout XML file.

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_message"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/app_primary"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/app_primary_pressed"
    fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/app_ripple"/>
```

Download image of camera by clicking [here](https://icons8.com/web-app/for/all/camera).

**And you are done.**

Comment: I never tried using floating action button so far. Will let you know the result after try

Comment: @John if you try my solution then let me know that would it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use a shape and fill with your desire color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
    <solid android:color="#090" />  // solid for filling empty space

</shape>
```

> Use code in ImageButton

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:paddingBottom="140dp"
    android:src = "@drawable/camera"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Solid Tag

```
<solid android:color="#090" />
```

and replace `android:paddingBottom="140dp"` with `android:padding="whateversuitsyou"`

Answer (score 0):

Set width and height as below.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

This works for me. Try this...