# How to change icon size inside Floating Action Button?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

The default `Floating Action Button` is of size `56x56` and the icon size inside it has size `24x24`. I am using two `FABs` in my application and I want to use one FAB with `36*36` icon and other with `24*24` icon. I am not able to able to find a way to do so.

As suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38006173/1237141) answer, you can change the size of the icon by this code.

```
<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">36dp</dimen>
```

But using this code applies these dimens at a global level. Is there any way where I can set the icon size of the `FAB` individually?

Comment: You can not change it their are only two option mini and normal. If you want to use your own size button then use your custom implementation.

Comment: Yes, got it.. I have done some work around to achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: @thedarkpassenger can you share what workaround you have done to resize icon