# Floating button change attribute app:maxImageSize frome code

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-icons

I need to adjust icon size (increase) to floatingButton size which I change in code. 
In xml I can use attribute app:maxImageSize  from here [adjust-icon-size-of-floating-action-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484126/adjust-icon-size-of-floating-action-button-fab)

But I need to change FAB size in code so I need to change this attribute in code as well. But I did't manage to find suitable method fo FAB

Is there a way to set maxImageSize from code/adjust icon?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.