# ImageView won't match the parent instead showing white beside the image

Tags: android, imageview, image-size

I've often seen that I've you place an ImageView in a RelativeLayout in Android, and set its layout:width to match_parent, it won't size the image and make it bigger to fill the width, instead it show some white space besides the image. Why is that happening and how can I handle that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828720/what-is-default-scale-type-of-imageview

Comment: post the related xml so we can have a look