# Android: Image Displays way bigger than intended

Tags: android, photoshop, android-image

I am trying to build a Splash Screen with a logo at the center. From Photoshop i am exporting the image build for 480x800 to test.

My Design:

[image]

Android App

[image]

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textAlignment="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please read the docs about [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). You'll find that is the most comprehensive guide about this topic.

Comment: In which folder did you place your logo?

Comment: @dmon i put it in drawable folder

Comment: Plain `drawable`? Then that might be it. Have you tried putting it in `drawable-hdpi`?

Comment: @dmon yeah not its coming fine :D if there are shared resources where should i place them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When targeting high density devices (i.e. most newer phones) make sure you put your images in the appropriate drawable folder. In this case it sounds like the image should go in the `drawable-hdpi` folder due to its resolution.

What's happening is that since you placed it in the plain `drawable`, Android is assuming it to be `mdpi` and it upscales it for the phone (probably HDPI, so x1.5), which goes over the dimensions of the screen/ImageView, which causes it to be shown like that.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I'm unable to comment on your original post (me = to low rep?).

Anyway, could you please verify that the resolution of the image and the resolution of your screen are the same? If not, I guess some zooming/stretching may occur since the [default scale type for an ImageView is FIT_CENTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951923/whats-the-default-scaletype-of-imageview) which means that the image will be scaled. Could you please try to use [android:scaleType="center"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) instead and see what happens with the image?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

please try this one

Comment: can u please tell me what's the resolution  of your logo?

Comment: It's in the question: 480x800.